# Is there any data set containing list of windows software and the category each one of them belongs to?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-mining, windows

I wanted a dataset which lists many windows softwares according to their categories  for a project. eg: anaconda: software development, roblox: gaming, VLC: video player etc. I searched but could not find anything similar to this. Please link me to one of them if you are familiar to any such dataset.

Comment: Could a dataset of Android apps work?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen something along these lines produced by Microsoft as an "application compatibilty" list for version of windows but I cannot find a link at the moment

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this question

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t find an off-the-shelf dataset and have specific categories in mind, you could use the winget tags to crawl your own dataset (of winget listed software). e.g. by:

```
C:\Users\x>winget search --tag music
Name                                              ID                                  Version     Übereinstimmung Quelle
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Live Event Sound & Music Panel                    9WZDNCRDQVF1                        Unknown                     msstore
...
Music Mist                                        9WZDNCRDFGLG                        Unknown                     msstore
YouTube Music Desktop App                         Ytmdesktop.Ytmdesktop               1.13.0      Tag: music      winget
网易云音乐                                        xiaozhu188.electron-vue-cloud-music 1.2.3       Tag: music      winget
Kodi                                              XBMCFoundation.Kodi                 19.3.0.0    Tag: music      winget
Anvil Studio                                      WillowSoftware.AnvilStudio          21.08.01    Tag: music      winget
Harmony                                           VincentL.Harmony                    0.9.1       Tag: music      winget
Utsu                                              titinko.utsu                        0.4.5       Tag: music      winget
...
```

Winget is a native windows package manager, which is shipped with newer versions but can also be installed manually. For more information see: http://woshub.com/using-winget-package-manager-windows/

I would crawl it by writing a small Python script, but it may also be worth it to check out the winget REST api for this purpose: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource

Comment: i mean 'winget tags'...

Comment: Please add supporting information about winget and how to get access to the data.

Comment: I extended my post with some general information about winget / crawling.